# What is the shortest way to check if a variable exists and return an alternative in php?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, ternary-operator, ternary

When I check for a return value of a function I usually do this:

```
$my_value = get_field('some_field');
$my_value = $my_value ? $my_value : get_field('backup');
```

In Javascript I usually use `or` (`||`) to check a value and if not return an alternative i.e.

```
var my_value = get_field('some_field') || get_field('backup');
```

Is there something equivalent in `php`?

Comment: The ternary operator ( A ? B : C ) is the shortest way apart from binary operations like   A = B | C

Comment: It might not be applicable, but you could extend the `get_field` method, to be able to supply an optional default, so that, all you have to do is `$my_value = get_filed('some_field', get_field('backup'))`

Comment: @Martin Nice! Although in this use case it's an external function. But I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @BartłomiejWach What do you mean `A = B | C`? Never seen that in a use case.

Comment: It's explained properly here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even faster:

```
$my_value = get_field('some_field') ?: get_field('backup');
```

Note that it tests if `get_field('some_field')` is true or false, and if true, return its value, else `get_field('backup')`...

Comment: Nice, this is what I was aiming towards.

Comment: Again, make sure that the value of 'some_field' is never equivalent to false, like 0 or ''...

Answer (score 1):

well you have got it almost:

here is what helps you:

```
$my_value = isset($my_value) ? $my_value : get_field('backup');
```